# How to add PlayOnLinux's app shortcut to Plank?

Tags: plank, playonlinux

When I run some apps via PlayOnLinux, they are shown in Plank, but there is no way to pin them. How can I do that anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to add a .desktop file to ~/.local/share/applications

I would check to see if there is one in /usr/share/applications. If there is, copy that to the first directory I listed. If one does not exists, you might have to create one manually. But if you can launch it from the wingpanel than you have a valid .desktop file. It just need to be in the right place in order to pin it.